# A debug register substitute?

Tags: windows, debugging, cpu-registers

I was reading some old articles about debugging, and one of them mentioned the debug registers. Reading some more about these registers and what they can do made me incredibly eager to have some fun with them. However when I tried looking for some more information about how to actually use them I read that they can only be accessed from ring 0 in windows.

I thought that that was the end then, since I'm not going to write a kernel driver just to play with a few registers. But then I thought about the memory editing tool I used to play around with. Cheat engine it's called, and one of the various options of the program was to specify to break on instructions/data that was being executed/accessed/read. That is exactly the same as the debug registers do. So I was wondering: Is there a substitute/replacement for the debug registers in windows? Since I'm sure that the program (cheat engine) doesn't use a kernel driver to set these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not true at all, you can set HW debug register from ring3, indirectly (ollydbg does this), for this you need to use `SetThreadContext` under windows ([example](http://vovaprog.narod.ru/information/debug_exception.cpp.txt)).

if you still want a substitute for HW registers, you can use INT3 for code break points and single step trapping for checking if a varibale has changed(highly inefficient).

a good reference is GDB and its source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gdb/gdbint/gdbint_3.html

Comment: I was hoping more of a local solution, do you perhaps know if I can use something similar to SetThreadContext on my own process? EDIT: Never mind, MSDN says I can use it on my own process.

Comment: your answer is correct that you can use `SetThreadContext`, but the work doesn't happen in ring3. That function will boil down to a system call which switches to a ring0 service routine to do the real work.

Comment: @Evan: I know this, thats why I said **indirectly**. it really doesn't need the service routine though, you just need the ring0 privileged instruction permissions so you can do `MOV DRx,R32`